# How to get a URL as a argument from another URL

Tags: php, url, arguments

I have this URL:

```
http://localhost/login?destination=http://localhost/myweb/search?q=anything
```

Now I want to get this URL from the above URL:

```
http://localhost/myweb/search?q=anything
```

But `$_GET['destination'];` does not work..., Why? And how can I fix it?

It should be noted, here is my routing rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]  // I get the path usin$_GET['rt']

ErrorDocument 404 /error404.html
```

Comment: You need to `urlencode('http://localhost/myweb/search?q=anything')` that part.

Comment: @AbraCadaver and is it possible to decode it again ?

Comment: It will be decoded when you access `$_GET['destination']`.  But for reference http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php